# Define ng-model by name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very complex model, for example:

```
model = {
  "data_level1": {
    "data_level2": {
      "data_level3": {
        "data_level4": "myvalue"...
```

How can i avoid writing:

`<input type="text" ng-model="model.data_level1.data_level2.data_level3.data_level4"  />`

and write instead something like:

`<input type="text" ng-model="data_level4"  />`

Thanks.

Comment: You would anyway need to define this full path `model.data_level1.data_level2.data_level3.data_level4`: either in HTML or in controller.

Comment: How can I define it in controller? I know that each node of the model has a unique name.

Comment: Check Joao Leal's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in the controller:

```
$scope.subModel = $scope.model.data_level1.data_level2.data_level3;
```

And then:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="subModel.data_level4"  />
```

Note: you can't set `subModel` to `data_level4` because that is just a string, setting to `data_level3` will have `subModel` referencing the same object within your original `model`.

edit: added [pnlkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lQWMU77YQDN9HefoWuGW?p=preview) done by @ryanyuyu

Comment: Can't I "search" the model for the location of `data_level4`, without defining it explicitly?

Comment: off course you can, just navigate the properties of your model until you found the place to stop

Comment: [Demo of the idea](http://plnkr.co/edit/lQWMU77YQDN9HefoWuGW?p=preview).  Upon further scrutiny, my answer was really the same as this one.  So have an upvote.